# Vue Router how to scroll to same hash consecutively

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm currently working on a site based on Vue and using Vue Router for routing. My way to handle scroll behavior to anchor links is the following:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    scrollBehavior (to) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return { 
                selector: to.hash,
                offset: { x: 0, y: 140 }
            }
        }
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
})
```

And my links are built in the following way:

```
<router-link class="insurance-link d-block" to="#hogar">
    <img class="insurance-logo img-fluid" src="@/assets/home-icon.svg">
    Hogar
</router-link>
```

If I click on the link for the first time it scrolls to the anchor position fine, but if I scroll back to the top and click on it for the second time it won't scroll back to that position again. If I click on another anchor link and then click on the previous one everything works fine. Any ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: Maybe this is of help: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1668

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given I had limited time (and will, to be honest) to keep on trying solutions I opted to go with vue-anchor-router-link (https://github.com/mperator/vue-anchor-router-link), which worked like a charm. Thank you so much to everyone, your answers helped me understand better the way Vue and Vue Router handle anchor links.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix is to use `<a>` instead

```js
<a class="insurance-link d-block" href="#hogar">
    <img class="insurance-logo img-fluid" src="@/assets/home-icon.svg">
    Hogar
</a>
```

If you want to use `<router-link>` and make it work on the 2nd time you click on the router-link, you need to add custom onclick handler like this:

```html
<router-link class="insurance-link d-block" to="#hogar" @click.native="scrollToId('hogar')">
    <img class="insurance-logo img-fluid" src="@/assets/home-icon.svg">
    Hogar
</router-link>
```

and add to your vue methods:

```js
methods: {
  scrollToId(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, the `scrollIntoView()` works for me! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this behavior is due to Vue preventing the click event propagation, and when you're already at the clicked hash, the router considers it a non-change so ignores it. Vue docs state:

> In HTML5 history mode, router-link will intercept the click event so
> that the browser doesn't try to reload the page.

Using the `router-link` [default slot](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0) is one way to take more control. This seems to provide a workaround:

```
<router-link to="#hogar" v-slot="{ href }">
    <a :href="href">Hogar</a>
</router-link>
```

Comment: Hey Noah! Thanks for your answer. I've moved all my links to explicitly state path name and hash but sadly that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. I updated the answer with hopefully a better solution.