# Scrolling to anchors with Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I need an anchor link setup in vuejs to go to:

```html
<h1 id="apply">Test anchor</h1>
```

The following works but it changes the url to http://localhost:8080/#/apply

```
<a href="#apply" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Apply Now</a>
```

If I then refresh the page it doesn't know where to go.

The following doesn't work for me either. It doesn't even drop down to #apply.

```
<router-link to="/careers/job-1#apply">test</router-link>
```

How do I setup anchor links with vuejs routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `path` and a `hash` property to your `to` object:

```html
<router-link :to="{ path: '/careers/job-1', hash: '#apply' }">test</router-link>
```

And add `scrollBehavior` to your router definition:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  ...
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      };
    }
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };  // Go to the top of the page if no hash
  },
  ...
})
```

Now it should scroll (smoothly, unless you remove that `behavior` property) to the anchor defined by the hash

Comment: Yes the linter is complaining. I've removed it. That works great! Thanks!

Comment: One question. If I click the button for it to scroll. Then I manually scroll back up and click it again It doesn't anchor down. Have you found a way to combat this?

Comment: It's a good question with no built-in solution that I know of.  You can try one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529557/vue-router-how-to-scroll-to-same-hash-consecutively) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645657/2185093) is also a nice idea to use/expand on

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone else stumbles across this issue a couple of years after the question was asked, I found another way to achieve the desired behavior:

In my projects, I like to display the routes as an example on a navbar via the configured array passed to the createRouter() method of vue-router-4:

The key was simply to understand how vue-router works internally and that they have a property on the RouteRecordRaw class called redirect, which is a RouteRecordRedirectOption-Type. There we can define a hash to which it should navigate:

```
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    { name: 'home', path: '/', meta: { name: 'Home' }, component: () => import("@/pages/HomePage.vue") },
    { name: 'members', path: '/', meta: { name: 'Members'} , redirect: { name: 'home', hash: '#members' }},
    { name: 'events', path: '/', meta: { name: 'Events'} , redirect: { name: 'home', hash: '#events' }}
];
```

If we then pass this array into the createRouter method, we can access the list of routes in our navbar vue file via its getRoutes() method:

```
// router.ts
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: routes,
    scrollBehavior(to) {
        if (to.hash) return { el: to.hash, behavior: 'smooth' };
        return { top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' };
    }
});

// TheNavbar.vue
const routes = router.getRoutes();
```

This variable could then be accessed in the router-link tag like the following:

```
<router-link v-for="route in routes" :key="route.name" :to="route" class="nav-element">{{ route.meta.name }}</router-link>
```

For clarification above, I rarely use the property name of the RouteRecordRaw class to display it in my navbar, as it should be lowercase. That is the name of the route, not something we should display on the frontend (except in the url bar). So another approach is to put all miscellaneous information in the meta property.

I hope the above solution reaches the right people.